# Backward in time numerical integration with fixed time step

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Consider simple use of `NDSolve[]` function used to solve an ODE backward in time

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, -1, 0}]
```

With default settings one can obtain solution in domain $[-1,0]$. If I would like to use a fixed step integration with a priori choosen step size I would call

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, -1, 0}, 
 Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> Automatic, "StepSize" -> 1/10}]
```

The above code fails to give a result and complains

> NDSolve::sss: Unable to determine a starting step size for the method NDSolve`FixedStep. >>

Why is that the `"FixedStep"` method of `NDSolve[]` do not support backward in time integration?

Comment: I answered this yesterday...

Comment: @ciao Could you please provide a link to the answer?

Comment: Oh, sorry, It was leg-pulling, as in I answered it before you posted it, as in... backward in time...

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation to ["FixedStep" Method for NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html), I suggest

```
s = First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, -1, 0}, 
        StartingStepSize -> 1/10, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> Automatic}];
Plot[x[t] /. s, {t, -1, -0}, AxesLabel -> {x, t}]
```

[image]

The key change is to use `StartingStepSize` as an option instead of `"StepSize"` as a method.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this _solution_. But, isn't it a little bit too odd... I mean changing direction of integration shouldn't change the precedence of options? It still doesn't work when one specify both `StartingStepSize` and `StepSize` options.

Comment: @mmal. Yes, it is strange.  But, there are lots of strange things about Mathematica.

Comment: @mma It doesn't hurt to report it. Who knows if this can be added to the improvements list...

Comment: @mmal  I agree. Please do report this.

Comment: @P.Fonseca I think it does not. The purpose of this question was to see if anyone has a working solution, probably someone may know more about the `NDSolve` machinery and be able to explain observed behavior...

Comment: @mmal is this your way of saying that you would "prefer" that someone else repports it for you?